# Detect unicode language of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, html

I have a string that contains a few words. I want to find out all the words that contain only characters of Tamil Unicode. I am new to javascript.

Using Go, I do the same like:

```
            tokens := strings.Fields(stringContent, delim) // split based on delim, say space

            for _, token := range tokens { //like foreach
                r, l := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(token)
                if l != 1 {
                    if unicode.Is(unicode.Tamil, r) {
                        // Tamil word
                    }
                }
            }
```

I found that string.split() will give me the individual words based on the delimiter, in javascript. But I am not able to find out how to get if the word is a UTF-8 TAMIL word. Can someone help me achieve this in javascript ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy way is to do a regular expression match for words having characters in a unicode range

Hope this helps : http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

A sample with which you can start

```
"இந்தியா ASASAS எறத்தாழ ASSASAS குடியரசு ASWED SAASAS".match(/[\u0B80-\u0BFF]+/g);
```

Comment: I tried: <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
 alert("இந்தியா".match(/[\u0B80-\u0BFF]+/g);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
 but nothing happens.

Comment: btw the code I have shown will match only whole words. you have to modify the reg exp if you want to match a word which is a mix of tamil chars and english chars

Comment: Got it. The problem was because the default encoding on my browser was some western and so the alert was displaying as null. I changed it to UTF-8 and then the word displayed fine. Thanks.