# Two different font style in one page

Tags: html, css

I want to ask about CSS `font`.
I an using two languages in my site English and Arabic.
In the English I am using a `font-family` But when I change language to Arabic I lose the English font style and the same when I change to English.

How can I use two font style in the same page?

Ops: I cannot choose where the Arabic words coming and where the English letters coming the posts that will be added by users will decide it.

I'm using PHP, JS, CSS, JQ

Comment: What comes to mind is something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982937/detect-unicode-language-of-a-string-in-javascript 

Then have a javascript/jquery function to handle what font-family if it detects one language or another

Comment: Can you explain please?